# syntax error in create function MySql

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error with this simple sample script in MySql 5.6.17 :

```
CREATE FUNCTION sampldb.fn_x(param VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS int
BEGIN
return 1;
END
```

What am i doing wrong? In Sql workbench, the error is shown in the last 2 lines.

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Put a ; at end `end;`

Comment: It's just a generic syntax error. "You have an error in your SQL syntax. Check the manual...". Putting an ; at end makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION sampldb.fn_x(param VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS int
BEGIN
return 1;
END
//
```

Comment: And still use a semicolon after the END, some versions are sensitive about that.

Comment: DELIMITER did the trick! I mistakenly assumed that was required only when executing in the MySql monitor, and not in the workbench. I didn't need the ;